# Zend Framework Giving 404 Error For Controllers

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, mod-rewrite

I am using Zend Framework on Ubuntu 11.10 (my local dev machine). When I navigate to my application with this URL, the front page/index controller works fine:

```
http://localhost/myapp/public
```

So I know that for the most part everything is working. The problem comes when I try to access another controller with something like:

```
http://localhost/myapp/public/faq
```

This returns the 404 error "The requested URL /myapp/public/faq was not found on this server."

I used the Zend_Tool to create the controller like "zf create controller faq" which gave me FaqController.php with a default indexAction(). It also created the faq.phtml view. This all works just fine on my laptop (Windows XP) so I know it has to be something with configuration.

Here is my .htaccess (it's the default one):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

In an attempt to get it to work, I added this into my httpd.conf file and restarted apache:

```
<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

When that didn't work I tried putting that directly into my .htaccess file, but that was a no-go as well. What am I missing? What is stopping Zend from being able to rewrite and route requests?

Comment: i think you shouldn't access via the public folder directly in the url, how did you setup your virtual host? is .htaccess inside the public folder? is the public folder the `DocumentRoot` of your site in the virtual host settings?

Comment: What does your controller folders look like?

Comment: @JamesButler It's a standard Zend Framework directory created by "zf create project myapp"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SOLVED]**

Thanks for viewing, I ended up finding the solution. With Ubuntu, in the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ directory is a file called 000-default which contains configuration options.

I was unaware it was there, it had all the AllowOverride options set to None so I changed them to All, restarted Apache, and voila!

To ensure anybody who finds this question via search has full help, I'd like to pass on to make sure mod_rewrite is enabled (mine was) by opening a terminal and running:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

That is how you enable an Apache mod in Ubuntu.